# Parsec and user defined state

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm trying to implement js parser in haskell. But I'm stuck with automatic semicolon insertion. I have created [test project](https://github.com/zaretskysa/Jazzist/blob/semicolon/lab/ParserUserState/ParserUserState.hs) to play around with problem, but I can not figure out how to solve the problem.

In my test project program is a list of expressions (unary or binary):

```
data Program = Program [Expression]

data Expression
    = UnaryExpression Number
    | PlusExpression Number Number
```

Input stream is a list of tokens:

```
data Token
    = SemicolonToken
    | NumberToken Number
    | PlusToken
```

I want to parse inputs like these:
`1;` - Unary expression
`1 + 2;` - Binary expression
`1; 2 + 3;` - Two expressions (unary and binary)
`1 2 + 3;` - Same as previous input, but first semicolon is missing. So parser consume token 1, but token 2 is not allowed by any production of grammar (next expected token is semicolon or plus). Rule of automatic semicolon insertion says that in this case a semicolon is automatically inserted before token 2.

So, what is the most elegant way to implement such parser behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
expression = try unaryExpression <|> plusExpression
```

but that doesn't work, since a `UnaryExpression` is a prefix of a `PlusExpression`. So for

```
input2 = [NumberToken Number1, PlusToken, NumberToken Number1, SemicolonToken]
```

the parser happily parses the first `NumberToken` and automatically adds a semicolon, since the next token is a `PlusToken` and not a `SemicolonToken`. Then it tries to parse the next `Expression`, but the next is a `PlusToken`, no `Expression` can start with that.

Change the order in which the parsers are tried,

```
expression = try plusExpression <|> unaryExpression
```

and it will first try to parse a `PlusExpression`, and only when that fails resort to the shorter parse of a `UnaryExpression`.